# Change specific columns in a csv file into integer with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, format

I have a csv file that contains 6 columns in such format:

```
2021-04-13 11:03:13+02:00,3.0,3.0,3.0,12.0,12.0
```

Now I want to remove the decimal point of each column except for the first one.

I already tried using `df.style.format` aswell as the `df.astype(int)` and  `pd.set_option('precision', 0)` but in the latter two it always gets stuck on the first column, since that doesn't quiet fit ( `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2021-04-13 11:03:13+02:00'` )

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following. Using [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html) functionality of pandas.

```
df.iloc[:,1:] = df.iloc[:,1:].astype(int)
```

df will be as follows after running above code:

```
0,2021-04-13 11:03:13+02:00,3,3,3,12,12
```